# Replacing certain <a href..certain.domain.com... with php preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

So, I have a string of text:

```
string with a bunch of links but i need to simply get rid of these <a href="a.domain.com">Title</a> string with more links and text
```

I need to get rid of everything from `<a to a>` where `a.domain.com` is present (its always the same domain) using PHP preg_replace.
It seems so simple but I can't figure this out >.< or find anywhere that explains regex :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like this site for regexp: http://www.regular-expressions.info/
This isn't a full answer, but I would just match `<a [...]>[...]</a>` and make sure it's not greedy, so you don't end up tearing everything from the first occurance of `<a [...]>` all the way to the last `</a>`.
This was recommended in another forum, you might want to give it a try as well:

```
$rev= preg_replace('/<a href="([^<]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/', '', $_POST['rev']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to keep what's inside the `<a>` tags, you can try the [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) function.

If you want something more complicated, great tutorial for learning regular expressions is http://www.regular-expressions.info/

You can try something like

```
$no_tags = preg_replace('#<a (.*?)>(.*?)</a>#', '', $text);
```

but note that this will break if your tags are a more complex than the example you posted.

Comment: Nope, it just needs to delete the whole thing
Site looks good tho